# SSRS wrap data vertically in a row, 1 to 5 in col A, 6 to 10 in col B?

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

Is this possible in SSRS?

For each row there are currently ten values, but due to the lengthy labels, I'm looking at creating a slightly different output format.

What I'd like to achieve is this:

```
______________________________________________________

    DATAROW 1    label 1 : <#1 highest value>  | label 6 : <#6 highest value>
                 label 2 : <#2 highest value>  | label 7 : <#7 highest value>
                  .                ...         |  .               ...
                 label 5 : <#5 highest value>  | label 10: <#10 highest value>
______________________________________________________

    DATAROW 2    label 1 : <#1 highest value>  | label 6 : <#6 highest value>
                 label 2 : <#2 highest value>  | label 7 : <#7 highest value>
                  .                ...         |  .               ...
                 label 5 : <#5 highest value>  | label 10: <#10 highest value>
______________________________________________________

    DATAROW n    ...
```

So half the values appear in the left hand side of the row and half on the right hand side - there will always be ten values

There are two row groups and one column group in the report as is, not sure if changing it to the above format would change this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a column grouping based on

```
=if (#value < 6,1,2)
```

so 1-5 form the group "1"
with 6-10 forming the group "2"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try do it with subreports.

In each DataRow group make two collumns. First for labels from 1 to 5 and second from 6 to 10.
In each collumn insert subreport. 
Example for left column: subreport1 with get params **datarow1** and **colLeft**.

Comment: but how would you know which values to put in which column? You'd still need to use some kind of ranking functions to get you the relevant 'page' of results, and again it would still have to be done via MDX

Comment: Sorting. In left column by highest value, in right by lowest value. Do You have any procedure which You use in data set?

Comment: With hindsight, I probably should've labelled them at 6th, 7th.. highest rather than starting again. Will edit the q.